# Convert Scons-file to VisualStudio Project File

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, scons

Good afternoon.

I have a build script in Scons:

```
EnsureSConsVersion(0,14);

import string
import os
import os.path
import glob
import sys
import methods

methods.update_version()

# scan possible build platforms

platform_list = [] # list of platforms
platform_opts = {} # options for each platform
platform_flags = {} # flags for each platform


active_platforms=[]
active_platform_ids=[]
platform_exporters=[]
global_defaults=[]

for x in glob.glob("platform/*"):
    if (not os.path.isdir(x)):
        continue
    tmppath="./"+x

    sys.path.append(tmppath)
    import detect

    if (os.path.exists(x+"/export/export.cpp")):
        platform_exporters.append(x[9:])
    if (os.path.exists(x+"/globals/global_defaults.cpp")):
        global_defaults.append(x[9:])
    if (detect.is_active()):
        active_platforms.append( detect.get_name() )
        active_platform_ids.append(x);
    if (detect.can_build()):
        x=x.replace("platform/","") # rest of world
        x=x.replace("platform\\","") # win32
        platform_list+=[x]
        platform_opts[x]=detect.get_opts()
        platform_flags[x]=detect.get_flags()
    sys.path.remove(tmppath)
    sys.modules.pop('detect')

module_list=methods.detect_modules()


print "Detected Platforms: "+str(platform_list)
print("Detected Modules: "+str(module_list))

methods.save_active_platforms(active_platforms,active_platform_ids)

custom_tools=['default']

if (os.name=="posix"):
    pass
elif (os.name=="nt"):
    if (os.getenv("VSINSTALLDIR")==None):
    custom_tools=['mingw']

env_base=Environment(tools=custom_tools,ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']});
#env_base=Environment(tools=custom_tools);
env_base.global_defaults=global_defaults
env_base.android_source_modules=[]
env_base.android_source_files=[]
env_base.android_module_libraries=[]
env_base.android_manifest_chunk=""
env_base.disabled_modules=[]

env_base.__class__.android_module_source = methods.android_module_source
env_base.__class__.android_module_library = methods.android_module_library
env_base.__class__.android_module_file = methods.android_module_file
env_base.__class__.android_module_manifest = methods.android_module_manifest
env_base.__class__.disable_module = methods.disable_module

env_base.__class__.add_source_files = methods.add_source_files

customs = ['custom.py']

profile = ARGUMENTS.get("profile", False)
if profile:
    import os.path
    if os.path.isfile(profile):
        customs.append(profile)
    elif os.path.isfile(profile+".py"):
        customs.append(profile+".py")

opts=Options(customs, ARGUMENTS)
opts.Add('target', 'Compile Target (debug/profile/release).', "debug")
opts.Add('platform','Platform: '+str(platform_list)+'(sfml).',"")
opts.Add('python','Build Python Support: (yes/no)','no')
opts.Add('squirrel','Build Squirrel Support: (yes/no)','no')
opts.Add('tools','Build Tools (Including Editor): (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('lua','Build Lua Support: (yes/no)','no')
opts.Add('rfd','Remote Filesystem Driver: (yes/no)','no')
opts.Add('gdscript','Build GDSCript support: (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('vorbis','Build Ogg Vorbis Support: (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('minizip','Build Minizip Archive Support: (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('opengl', 'Build OpenGL Support: (yes/no)', 'yes')
opts.Add('game', 'Game (custom) Code Directory', "")
opts.Add('squish','Squish BC Texture Compression (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('theora','Theora Video (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('freetype','Freetype support in editor','yes')
opts.Add('speex','Speex Audio (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('xml','XML Save/Load support (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('png','PNG Image loader support (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('jpg','JPG Image loader support (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('webp','WEBP Image loader support (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('dds','DDS Texture loader support (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('pvr','PVR (PowerVR) Texture loader support (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('builtin_zlib','Use built-in zlib (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('musepack','Musepack Audio (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add('default_gui_theme','Default GUI theme (yes/no)','yes')
opts.Add("CXX", "Compiler");
opts.Add("nedmalloc", "Add nedmalloc support", 'yes');
opts.Add("CCFLAGS", "Custom flags for the C++ compiler");
opts.Add("CFLAGS", "Custom flags for the C compiler");
opts.Add("LINKFLAGS", "Custom flags for the linker");
opts.Add('disable_3d', 'Disable 3D nodes for smaller executable (yes/no)', "no")
opts.Add('disable_advanced_gui', 'Disable advance 3D gui nodes and behaviors (yes/no)', "no")
opts.Add('old_scenes', 'Compatibility with old-style scenes', "yes")

# add platform specific options

for k in platform_opts.keys():
    opt_list = platform_opts[k]
    for o in opt_list:
        opts.Add(o[0],o[1],o[2])

for x in module_list:
    opts.Add('module_'+x+'_enabled', "Enable module '"+x+"'.", "yes")

opts.Update(env_base) # update environment
Help(opts.GenerateHelpText(env_base)) # generate help

# add default include paths

env_base.Append(CPPPATH=['#core','#core/math','#tools','#drivers','#'])

# configure ENV for platform    
env_base.detect_python=True
env_base.platform_exporters=platform_exporters

"""
sys.path.append("./platform/"+env_base["platform"])
import detect
detect.configure(env_base)
sys.path.remove("./platform/"+env_base["platform"])
sys.modules.pop('detect')
"""

if (env_base['target']=='debug'):
    env_base.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DDEBUG_MEMORY_ALLOC']);
    env_base.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DSCI_NAMESPACE'])

env_base.platforms = {}

for p in platform_list:

    sys.path.append("./platform/"+p)
    import detect
    if "create" in dir(detect):
        env = detect.create(env_base)
    else:
        env = env_base.Clone()

    CCFLAGS = env.get('CCFLAGS', '')
    env['CCFLAGS'] = ''

    env.Append(CCFLAGS=string.split(str(CCFLAGS)))
    detect.configure(env)
    env['platform'] = p
    sys.path.remove("./platform/"+p)
    sys.modules.pop('detect')

    flag_list = platform_flags[p]
    for f in flag_list:
                env[f[0]] = f[1]

    env.module_list=[]

    for x in module_list:
        if env['module_'+x+'_enabled'] != "yes":
            continue
        tmppath="./modules/"+x
        sys.path.append(tmppath)
        env.current_module=x
        import config
        if (config.can_build(p)):
            config.configure(env)
            env.module_list.append(x)
        sys.path.remove(tmppath)
        sys.modules.pop('config')


    if (env['musepack']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DMUSEPACK_ENABLED']);

    if (env["old_scenes"]=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DOLD_SCENE_FORMAT_ENABLED'])
    if (env["rfd"]=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DRFD_ENABLED'])
    if (env["builtin_zlib"]=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPPATH=['#drivers/builtin_zlib/zlib'])

    if (env['squirrel']=='yes'):

        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DSQUIRREL_ENABLED'])
        env.Append(CPPPATH=['#script/squirrel/src'])

    # to test 64 bits compiltion
    # env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-m64'])

    if (env['lua']=='yes'):

        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DLUA_ENABLED'])
        env.Append(CPPPATH=['#script/lua/src'])
    if (env_base['squish']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DSQUISH_ENABLED']);

    if (env['vorbis']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DVORBIS_ENABLED']);

    if (env['theora']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DTHEORA_ENABLED']);

    if (env['png']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DPNG_ENABLED']);
    if (env['dds']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DDDS_ENABLED']);
    if (env['pvr']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DPVR_ENABLED']);
    if (env['jpg']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DJPG_ENABLED']);
    if (env['webp']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DWEBP_ENABLED']);

    if (env['speex']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DSPEEX_ENABLED']);

    if (env['tools']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DTOOLS_ENABLED'])
    if (env['disable_3d']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-D_3D_DISABLED'])
    if (env['gdscript']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DGDSCRIPT_ENABLED'])
    if (env['disable_advanced_gui']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DADVANCED_GUI_DISABLED'])

    if (env['minizip'] == 'yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DMINIZIP_ENABLED'])

    if (env['xml']=='yes'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DXML_ENABLED'])

    if (env['default_gui_theme']=='no'):
        env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DDEFAULT_THEME_DISABLED'])

    if (env["python"]=='yes'):
        detected=False;
        if (env.detect_python):
            print("Python 3.0 Prefix:");
            pycfg_exec="python3-config"
            errorval=os.system(pycfg_exec+" --prefix")
            prefix=""
            if (not errorval):
                #gah, why can't it get both at the same time like pkg-config, sdl-config, etc?
                env.ParseConfig(pycfg_exec+" --cflags")
                env.ParseConfig(pycfg_exec+" --libs")
                detected=True

        if (detected):
            env.Append(CPPFLAGS=['-DPYTHON_ENABLED'])
            #remove annoying warnings
            if ('-Wstrict-prototypes' in  env["CCFLAGS"]):
                env["CCFLAGS"].remove('-Wstrict-prototypes');
            if ('-fwrapv' in env["CCFLAGS"]):
                env["CCFLAGS"].remove('-fwrapv');
        else:
            print("Python 3.0 not detected ("+pycfg_exec+") support disabled.");

    #if env['nedmalloc'] == 'yes':
    #   env.Append(CPPFLAGS = ['-DNEDMALLOC_ENABLED'])

    Export('env')

    #build subdirs, the build order is dependent on link order.

    SConscript("core/SCsub")
    SConscript("servers/SCsub")
    SConscript("scene/SCsub")
    SConscript("tools/SCsub")
    SConscript("script/SCsub");
    SConscript("drivers/SCsub")
    SConscript("bin/SCsub")

    if env['game']:
        SConscript(env['game']+'/SCsub')

    SConscript("modules/SCsub")
    SConscript("main/SCsub")

    SConscript("platform/"+p+"/SCsub"); # build selected platform
```

This script collects game engine Godot (http://www.godotengine.org) 
I want to convert this script in the project file of Visual Studio 2010. 
In Scons have corresponding command env.MSVSProject(). 
Description:

> Builds a Microsoft Visual Studio project file, and by default builds a solution file as well.Example usage:
>
> barsrcs = ['bar.cpp'], barincs = ['bar.h'], barlocalincs =
>   ['StdAfx.h'] barresources = ['bar.rc','resource.h'] barmisc =
>   ['bar_readme.txt']
>
> dll = env.SharedLibrary(target = 'bar.dll',
>                           source = barsrcs)
>
> env.MSVSProject(target = 'Bar' + env['MSVSPROJECTSUFFIX'],
>                   srcs = barsrcs,
>                   incs = barincs,
>                   localincs = barlocalincs,
>                   resources = barresources,
>                   misc = barmisc,
>                   buildtarget = dll,
>                   variant = 'Release')

More - http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/a8304.html

But I do not understand how to pass the appropriate parameters, as they choose from a script.

Tell me, please.

Answer (score 1):

The MSVSProject builder can create a Visual Studio project but it's only a project for you library with your files in them. You can't convert a SCons' configuration file to a VS project.
The builder only serve for people that wanted to work in Visual Studio IDE. But you need to continue compile with the scons command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to achieve what you want to achieve by properly configuring your project.
In the project's property page, under 'NMake' settings make sure that these parameters reflect the scons build command

- Build command line: (eg: scons -C ....\ debug=1)
- Rebuild All command line: (eg: scons -C ....\ -c && scons -C ....\ debug=1)
- Clean command line: the scons command line to clean the project

These values should also be set to their proper values:

- Output: (i.e. executable name)

In the project's property page, under 'General' settings make sure that these parameters correspond to:

- Configuration Type: Makefile

You can find a complete description of the above at http://grbd.github.io/posts/2016/07/27/scons-builds-with-visual-studio/